# Difference between "peak at" and "peak for"

Tags: word-usage

I need to say that a variable Y reaches its maximum value when X=1.

Is there any difference between saying "its value peaks at X=1" and saying "its value peaks for X=1"?

Comment: Why would you not just use **when**, exactly as you did in the question itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question of mathematical convention. You may use either construction. There is little or no difference in meaning.

In my own scientific experience, "...peaks for X=1" suggests (but only rather weakly) that X is a variable over which we may have some control, whereas "... peaks at X=1" suggests (again, only weakly) that the peaking is a matter of observation rather than control.